# Determine All Divisors of $f(x)=x^n\in F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, divisibility

Carefully determine all divisors of $f(x)$ where $$ f(x)=x^n\in F[x]$$
note that $F[x]$ is a Field

---

So, $$ \underbrace{x^0\mid x^n,\ x^1\mid x^n,\dots,\ x^n\mid x^n}_{n+1}$$
making $n+1$ divisors.

***ify on Associates?***
$x^n$ has an associate $a x^n$ because $f(x)=a^{-1} (a x^n)$.

The associate does divide $x^n$ since F is a field and evry element including $a$ is a unit.
$$ ax^n \mid x^n \equiv \exists a^{-1}:x^n=1_R(x^n)=(a^{-1})ax^n$$

Comment: That is everything, up to associates (two divisors which differ only by an invertible factor/unit).  You haven't told us what $F$ is, though we can assume you mean a ring, possibly a field, to make sense of the polynomial construction.

Comment: @hardmath F is assumed to be a Field. R would be assumed to be a Ring. Anyways, just add a line about also the associates. Thanks.

Comment: I mention it because your assignment says "carefully determine".

Comment: Maybe what's missing is a proof that there can be no other divisors besides the ones listed. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I do think associates are divisors since we are in a Field. edited the question to reflect it.

Comment: @Hugo : ok, but there's still the question of proving there are no other divisors. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I agree, at least an "offer" of proof would be nice. For example, if (as clarified) $F$ is a field, a summary invocation that $F[x]$ is a UFD might be sufficient (depending on where the class has gotten).  And, Hugo, I was suggesting not only the associates of $x^n$ but also the associates of lower powers of $x$ be listed as divisors.

Comment: @hardmath  I understand all the associates lower powers are also divisors. I have 10 more problems to go over. I think this is sufficient for the my class level.